# PhpStorm "Unknown named parameter" Error With CakePHP 5.x

Tags: php, cakephp, phpstorm

I recently created a new project in CakePHP 5 which is PHP 8.1+ compatible and accepts named parameters. I freshly baked a model and in the controller, when using PhpStorm (2023.1.2), I get a highlighted error.

Note that the code itself executes fine, it's PhpStorm that is calling it an error.

The tutorial/baked controller errors out in the editor with the following (`Components` is a `hasMany` relationship):

```
    public function view(?string $id = null): void
    {
        $unit = $this->Units->get($id, contain: ['Components']);
        $this->set(compact('unit'));
    }
```

PhpStorm gives me:

```
Unknown named parameter 'contain'
```

Prior to CakePHP 5, the syntax was:

```
    public function view(?string $id = null): void
    {
        $unit = $this->Units->get($id, ['contain' => ['Components']]);
        $this->set(compact('unit'));
    }
```

Comment: Dave you installed https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-ide-helper ?

Comment: See https://github.com/cakephp/bake/issues/944 and related PR that already fixed it

Answer (score 0):

The `cakephp-ide-helper` / `bake` issue is solved. Try updating with `composer update` and **bake your annotations** again.

Then your Table-classes should have updated annotations and the PhpStorm error should be gone because of the updated annotations.